# Are there any applications on the Mac to help create a bootable ubuntu USB stick

Tags: macos, ubuntu, usb, boot

Are there any applications on the mac which would allow me to burn my ubuntu iso to a USB stick (I am not good at terminal.) Also, is there any way to make sure that a bootable stick created on the mac is usable on windows? Lastly, I only have a 1.87 GB stick. Will this be enough to hold ubuntu? I can also use a larger stick (8.00 GB) if the other one is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in 'Disk Utility'.

1. Open up Disk Utility (Click Spotlight [or <kbd>CMD+Space</kbd>] and type "Disk").
2. From there, select the desired USB, select the 'Restore' option
3. The source should be the ISO and destination is the USB.

Yes, around 1gb is more than enough for a typical Ubuntu live disc.

Sorry for the lack of screenshots, I no longer own a mac.

Comment: I tried to do that, but the option for the .iso was greyed out. Why is that?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Could you be a little more specific?  Try dragging the downloaded ISO into the white space on the left - it should show up there.  **Then** drag the iso from there into the 'Source' field. There isn't any iso button or option necessary.

Comment: I read http://askubuntu.com/a/12049, but I am not sure what `~/path/to/target.img `. Can you please explain that?

Comment: That shouldn't matter here, I've never had to do that...

Comment: Ok... that seems to work better. Are you sure that I don't need to convert it to `.img`?

Comment: I never did, I would try it this way. If that fails to work, let me know and we can go from there.

Comment: I did everything, but I got a failure message - never a good sign. The computer was unable to do it. I got: `Restore Failure. Could not validate source - Invalid argument.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8306/discussion-between-nerdwaller-and-xxmbabanexx)